# why is x private in var myObject: Object = { x: 1 };

Tags: typescript1.4

Declare

```
var myObject: Object = { x: 1 };
```

Use/assign

```
myObject.x // <- property x does not exist on type Object
```

I'm assuming because x is private, but then what's the point of defining an object this way or making x private?

[TS Playground Sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20points%3A%20Object%20%3D%20%7B%20x%3A%201%20%7D%3B%20%0Apoints.x)

Comment: `Object` at that place is kind of an interface for `{ x: 1 }` beacuse `myObject` will be of "type" `Object` it doesn't know that it hat the x property but x is not private.

Comment: @mash Is there any point in doing myObject like that?

Comment: Well yeah for example if you don't want to use <number> to enforce type of initally nulled values or if you want the object to implement an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Object is defined by TypeScript as an interface in the definition file: lib.d.ts - interface Object { ... }

'x' is not a member of that interface and because myObject is of type Object and Object is an interface you cannot see any members that are not on the interface. You also cannot add x on the fly, as in traditional JavaScript:

```
myObject.x = 4;
```

TypeScript was created to add structure and typing to JavaScript - at least at compile time.

If you want to access your x you can expand the Object interface. Your code can look like this:

```
interface Object {
    x : number;
}

var myObject: Object = { x: 1 };

var myX = myObject.x; // No TypeScript error here.
```